# Check values or pattern in one dataframe column against another column in Data Base to see if match appears

Tags: r

Same like below how to get the output if I am getting data from SQL.

Example dataset: MRN is patient ID

```
Brand <- c("Evista", "Rozerem", "Altace")

MRN <- c("121212", "121212", "231212", "432123", "432123", "542345", 
"323412", "242341", "412111", "642321")

MedList <- c("raloxifene 60mg daily", "Rozerem 8mg daily", "evista 60mg 
daily", "metoprolol tartate 25mg twice daily", "ramelteon 8mg daily", 
"ramipril 5mg daily", "omeprazole 20mg daily", "ALTACE 5mg nightly", 
"ramelteon 8mg daily", "imatinib 400mg daily")
```

Query :

```
grepl(paste(toupper(Brand), collapse = '|'), toupper(MedList))

 [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE



===========================================================
```

Example:

```
rm(list=ls()) Brand <- c("Evista", "Rozerem", "Altace")

MRN <- c("121212", "121212", "231212", "432123", "432123", "542345", "323412", "242341", "412111", "642321")

---getting this from data base----
MedList <- data.frame(DiagnosticNotes = data[, "nvchDiagnosticNotes"])
---getting this from data base----
Patients <- data.frame(MRN,MedList)
```

Do I need to chnage the below query:

```
grepl(paste(toupper(Brand), collapse = '|'), toupper(MedList))
```

Comment: I think you need `grepl(paste(toupper(Brand), collapse = '|'), toupper(MedList$DiagnosticNotes))` to extract the column.  If it is a data.frame column inside a data.frame, then you may need `Patients$MedList$DiagnosticNotes`, not clear about the structure

Comment: Akrun, is it possible to show in another line which brand is matching  out of 3 ?\